# What am I doing wrong here with using sandbox over my iframe?

Tags: html, iframe, sandbox

Here is the code of my first file, which embeds an `<iframe>`,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <iframe src="atag.html" frameborder="0" height="500px" width="500px" sandbox>
    </iframe>
</body>

</html>
```

Here is the code of my file `atag.html`

```
<html lang="en">
<title>Document</title>

<body>
    <a
        href="https://imageio.forbes.com/specials-images/imageserve/5d35eacaf1176b0008974b54/2020-Chevrolet-Corvette-Stingray/0x0.jpg?format=jpg&crop=4560,2565,x790,y784,safe&width=960">
        Click here</a>
</body>

</html>
```

However, when I click on the 'Click here' inside the iframe, it opens up the image I link through href. Which in my opinion should not work, because it is sandboxed.
I don't know what I am doing wrong... Help required...